# Form sending data to controller once, then it doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, spring, forms, jsp

I have a jsp with a board to play tic tac toe. And after each click on it I send the clicked field to Spring controller. Then I find best move for a computer and display a board with moves of me and of computer. The problem is that after first move, clicking on another field doesn't do anything, script works only once. And changing parameters in URL manually change position of my move, but doesn't make another one.

Code of the form with a board ("game.jsp"):

```
%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt" %>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Game</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    function redirect(x, y) {
        window.location = "http://localhost:8080/taskNine/move?x=" + x + "&y=" + y;
    }
</script>
    <FORM NAME="tic" method="post" accept-charset=utf-8>
    <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="sqr1" class="tictac" value="${board[0][0]}" onClick="if(document.tic.sqr1.value == '') {document.tic.sqr1.value = 'X';redirect(0, 0); }">
    <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="sqr2" class="tictac" value="${board[0][1]}" onClick="if(document.tic.sqr2.value == '') {document.tic.sqr2.value = 'X';redirect(0, 1); }">
    <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="sqr3" class="tictac" value="${board[0][2]}" onClick="if(document.tic.sqr3.value == '') {document.tic.sqr3.value = 'X';redirect(0, 2); }"> <br />
    <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="sqr4" class="tictac" value="${board[1][0]}" onClick="if(document.tic.sqr4.value == '') {document.tic.sqr4.value = 'X';redirect(1, 0); }">
    <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="sqr5" class="tictac" value="${board[1][1]}" onClick="if(document.tic.sqr5.value == '') {document.tic.sqr5.value = 'X';redirect(1, 1); }">
    <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="sqr6" class="tictac" value="${board[1][2]}" onClick="if(document.tic.sqr6.value == '') {document.tic.sqr6.value = 'X';redirect(1, 2); }"> <br />
    <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="sqr7" class="tictac" value="${board[2][0]}" onClick="if(document.tic.sqr7.value == '') {document.tic.sqr7.value = 'X';redirect(2, 0); }">
    <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="sqr8" class="tictac" value="${board[2][1]}" onClick="if(document.tic.sqr8.value == '') {document.tic.sqr8.value = 'X';redirect(2, 1); }">
    <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="sqr9" class="tictac" value="${board[2][2]}" onClick="if(document.tic.sqr9.value == '') {document.tic.sqr9.value = 'X';redirect(2, 2); }"> <br />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is a controller snippet:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/move", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String fieldMove(@RequestParam("x") int x, @RequestParam("y") int y, ModelMap model) {

    gameService.move(x, y, model);
    return "game";
}
```

Comment: Why do you need `window.location`?

Comment: I send the data (parameters) to controller to process it and return move of the computer.

Comment: I think you need to use Ajax for that!

Answer (score 0):

The name of the RequestParam has to match with the name of the input:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/move", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String fieldMove(@RequestParam("sqr1") int sqr1, @RequestParam("sqr2") int sqr1, ..., ModelMap model) {

// Do something
return "game";
```

}

Comment: I'll check it, but why the function redirect works only once? It would be easier that way.